# Container props changing after state changes within children

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm using React 15.5.4 and Redux 3.6.0.

Currently I'm passing an array of Objects to a container through Redux. That in turn is passing the array to a list component. The list will reorder the array depending on what sorting order has been selected, and send each item to it's own individual component. There are no actions within the list or individual components, the list can only change it's own state. For some reason when the list is changing order it is also changing the order of it's parent component. Which makes no sense.

No actions are being dispatched, and there are no functions in place that go up from the list to the container. The re ordered list itself isn't being set in state or saved anywhere. I'm just mapping over it. Something is wrong that the Container's props are changing when the list-component is resorting the list that was passed to it through props, but I have no idea why that should be.

Has anyone seen this issue before or know what could be the cause?

Comment: You should probably add code if you want to see an answer to this question. Redux setups are difficult enough to debug with code.

Comment: What do you mean by "reorder" the array? are you using `.sort`?

Comment: I am, yes. When a new setting is chosen in the list-component it's state will change. Based on that the attributes used to sort will change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this might be a thing of Javascript more than a thing of React:

```
let arr1 = [6,5,4,3,2,1]
let arr2 = arr1
console.log(arr1) // [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
console.log(arr2) // [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

//note that at this point, they have the same values in the same order
arr1.sort() //sort arr1, NOT arr2
console.log(arr1) //[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
console.log(arr2) //[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Notice that even tho we did not change arr2, it was still sorted. This is because you are passing the reference to the array itself, not a new array/ Any changes that you make on arr2, will be reflected on arr1 because they both *are* the same array, you are just *calling* two different names.

When passing the array from the container to the components that sorts them, instead pass it by "spreading" it into another array, like this `arr2 = [...arr1]` that way both arr1 and arr1 are different arrays, and the changes on arr2 will not be reflected on arr1.

More info on the spread operator here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator

Useful stuff! Usable on arrays and objects also.

Comment: FTW, I did as you recommended and it solved my problem immediately. Thanks for your help / insight. I thought I had addressed this issue by using Object.assign within the Container and putting all the List's props together into a new object I was passing in like <List {...props} />. But that seems to have kept the reference to the container's props.

Comment: I think the spread is nice, but it's useful to point out that `.slice` does the same job.

Comment: @azium that's true. In my opinion, tho, it's not the intended use for slice, and using more modern syntax is good behavior. but if spread operator does not work or you'd rather not use it, `.slice` will work every time!

Comment: @user2684405 you were almost in the right track! Using the spread operator like that will mean that you are passing a copy of props, but everything inside of it it a reference (or a value, depending if you're passing an array or object or variable inside of props)

Answer (score -1):

You might need to add a shouldComponentUpdate function to the parent component and control when/if it should update based on data changes.

You can check out the docs here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate